# Azure YAML conditional expressions Powershell task

Tags: azure, powershell, yaml, devops

So I have this YAML setup as follows

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Execute script'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/scripts/test_script.ps1'
    ${{ if eq(variables.SetConfig, false) }}:
       arguments: '-ProjectName $(ProjectName) -Environment $(Environment)'
    ${{ if eq(variables.SetConfig, true) }}:
       arguments: '-ProjectName $(ProjectName) -Environment $(Environment) -SetConfig'
```

I'm trying to achieve a flow where a pipeline doesn't always set the config files, only if the deploy is done from scratch. This is to prevent the server (IIS) from recycling.

My *test_script.ps1* is CmdletBinding with the `$ProjectName` and `$Environment` as Mandatory params and the `$SetConfig` as a switch.

Now, when trying this flow in the Azure pipelines, I get the following error.

```
test_script.ps1: /home/vsts/work/_temp/64e94b5b-8cf3-47b6-b01a-8a487cddabe2.ps1:2
Line |
   2 |  . '/home/vsts/work/1/scripts/test_script.ps1'
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot process command because of one or more missing
     | mandatory parameters: ProjectName Environment.
```

This means it doesn't recognize the `arguments` statement when the `$SetConfig` is either `true` or `false`.

The variables are correctly set and give the correct values as seen below. This step was triggered just before it.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Debug parameters'
  inputs:
    targetType: Inline
    script: |
      Write-Host "Environment $(Environment)"
      Write-Host "ProjectName $(ProjectName)"
      Write-Host "SetConfig $(SetConfig)"
```

Output:

```
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command . '/home/vsts/work/_temp/19910ca4-c3e7-403a-a75c-fe0dd276e711.ps1'
Environment Development
ProjectName test_project
SetConfig true
```

Does the conditional expression not work in this case?

Comment: Personally, I'd move the conditional out of the YAML and into the Powershell script, and make -SetConfig a normal parameter.

Comment: Yes I thought about that aswell, but a switch parameters is cleaner in the CmdletBinding. That's the only reason I'm trying this.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but the problem is caused by a using a runtime variable in a compile time expression.

yaml template statements in curly braces are compile time statements and won't have access to runtime variable values.  At compile time, the variables will be empty strings.

For the function `eq` the right parameter is cast to the left parameter type.

The condition `${{ if eq(variables.SetConfig, false) }}:` would evaluate to `${{ if eq('', 'false') }}:`

[bool docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#boolean-1)

[eq docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#eq)

Because you're comparing "" to "true" or "false", neither leg of the if statements are injected and you're calling the powershell script with no arguments in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine I believe, please double check your `ProjectName` and `Environment` variables. There is no reason it should not work with the `arguments` parameter.

Working example:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

variables:
 foo: true
 bar: barbar

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    ${{ if eq(variables.foo, false) }}:
      script: |
        # Write your commands here
        echo 'Hello world'
    ${{ if eq(variables.foo, true) }}:
      script: |
        # Write your commands here
        echo 'Hello $(bar)'
```

Another example in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-set-a-task-input):

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
      artifact: 'prod'
    ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
      artifact: 'dev'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

Comment: Hi Alex, the variables are correctly set and give the correct values. I've added them to my original question.